# Partial View Update using Ajax refreshing the whole page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action method which returns a partial View and I am calling the controller action method from the Main Index View like below.

### Controller

```
    public PartialViewResult GetEmployee(int val)
    {
        var employee = db.getEmployeeById(val)
        return PartialView("_PatialEmployeeView", employee);
    }
```

### Index View Which calls Partial

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Get Employee</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Input)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Input)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Input)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input id="GetEmp" type="submit" value="Run" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div id="EmployeeResults">
</div>
```

And my Javascript to make the AJAX request is as below.

```
$('#GetEmp').click(function (e) {
        var empId = document.getElementById("GetEmp").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployee", "Home")',
            type: "get", //send it through get method
            data: { val: empId },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#EmployeeResults").html(data);
                //Do Something
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("FAILED");
                //Do Something to handle error
            }
        });
    });
```

In above, whenever i enter employee id value in the text box and submit the form...I want to attach the results from the partial View to the div (EmployeeResults) element. I get the partial View results back, but the whole page gets refreshed everytime i submit the form and as a result I don't see the partial view output.

Could someone point what I am doing wrong and how I can display just the partial view without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Why don't you use `Ajax.BeginForm()`?

Comment: if you change the type of the button to `type="button"` it should work. And then the Begin form is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting a form causes the page to refresh, unless you prevent the default action:

```
$('#GetEmp').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```